# Internal Server Error: /pluscart/, app.models.Cart.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Cart -- it returned 8

Tags: python, django, ajax

```
views.py


from django.db.models import Count
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from . models import Product, Cart, Customer
from . forms import CustomerRegistrationFrom, CustomerProfileForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Q

def plus_cart(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        prod_id=request.GET['prod_id']
        c = Cart.objects.get(Q(product=prod_id) & Q (user=request.user))
        c.quantity+=1
        c.save()
        user = request.user
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        amount = 0
        for p in cart:
            value = p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
            amount = amount + value
        totalamount = amount + 40
        #print(prod_id)
        data={
            'quantity':c.quantity,
            'amount':amount,
            'totalamount':totalamount,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)



script.js


$('.plus-cart').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("pid").toString();
    var eml = this.parentNode.children[2]
    console.log("pid =",id)
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/pluscart",
        data:{
            prod_id:id
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log("data = ",data);
            eml.innerHTML = data.quantity
            document.getElementById("amount").innerText=data.amount
            document.getElementById("totalamount").innerText=data.totalamount
        }
    })
})
```

```
Internal Server Error: /pluscart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\OneDrive\Desktop\E-com\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\OneDrive\Desktop\E-com\ec\app\views.py", line 127, in plus_cart
    c = Cart.objects.get(Q(product=prod_id) & Q (user=request.user))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\OneDrive\Desktop\E-com\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\OneDrive\Desktop\E-com\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 640, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
app.models.Cart.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Cart -- it returned 8!
[07/May/2023 20:18:49] "GET /pluscart/?prod_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 77472
```

Here am try to increase the quantity but it shows error

Comment: Well as the error indicates, you somehow made multiple `Cart`s for the same user and product_id.

Comment: Although not the core problem, you are violating the HTTP protocol, since a GET request is not supposed to have side-effects.

Comment: Can you provide the `Product` model source code? Seems like you are allowing user to have more than one product with the same id...

Comment: @allexiusw: no normally it is the cart, it is also normally impossible, since a `ForeignKey` checks that the field it refers to is unique itsef. So if you refer to the primary key (which is default) that should be unique.

Comment: Yes I meant `Cart` model sorry.

Comment: Please share the source code (update your post) with the code related to:
Cart, User (in case it's overwritten), and Product.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a model like the following:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    //Built-in id that is autogenerated in each Django model.
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So you are passing the following two variables to the view:
`request.user` and `prod_id` so at the time you are filtering you can potentially get more than one product that are related to `Product` and `User`. To fix your problem what you should do is instead of passing to the view the `product_id` you must pass the `Cart.id` in that way you can filter something like the following:

```
def plus_cart(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        pk = request.GET['cart_id']
        c = Cart.objects.get(pk=pk, user=request.user)
        c.quantity+=1
        c.save(update_fields=['quantity'])
        user = request.user
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        amount = 0
        for p in cart:
            value = p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
            amount = amount + value
        totalamount = amount + 40
        #print(prod_id)
        data={
            'quantity':c.quantity,
            'amount':amount,
            'totalamount':totalamount,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

You have to make sure in the frontend that the `Cart.id` is sent to the backend in the AJAX method and then you will get it working.